# Android listview load image storage and downloaded

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-listview, android-asynctask

I use listview and custom adapter. Adapter load image storage and download stroge and showing.

Problem, download and install all the files until the imageview seems random photos. After the download is complete, all the photos look normal.

```
public class NewsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsData>{
List<NewsData> items;
Context context;
public HaberListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<NewsData> haberArray) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, haberArray);
    this.items = haberArray;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View v=convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_haber_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtCaption = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtCaption);
        holder.txtContent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
        holder.txtDate= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        holder.imageView= (ImageView)  v.findViewById(R.id.image);

        v.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }


    final NewsData o = items.get(position);


    if (o != null) {
        holder.txtCaption.setText(o.getCaption());
        holder.txtContent.setText(o.getContent());
        holder.txtDate.setText(o.getTarih());

        if (o.getimageStatus()==0)
        {
            String[] params={ String.valueOf(o.getID()),o.getImageWebUrl()};
            new setDownloadImage(holder.imageView,position).execute(params);
        }
        else
        {
            String imagePath = context.getFilesDir().toString() +"/news"+o.getID()+".jpg";
            File fs=new File(imagePath);
            if (fs.exists()) 
                holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
            else
            {
                dataBase db=new dataBase(context);
                db.setimageStatus(o.getID(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
    if (position % 2 == 0)
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    else 
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D4E4FD"));
    return v;

}

class ViewHolder {

    public  TextView txtCaption,txtContent,txtDate;
    public ImageView imageView;

}



class setDownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    private int position;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    public setDownloadImage(ImageView imageView,int position)
    {
        this.position=position;
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String f_url=params[1];
        String id=params[0];
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(context.getFilesDir()+"/news"+id+".jpg");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

            return id;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (!result.equals(""))
        {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            String imagePath = context.getFilesDir().toString() +"/news"+result+".jpg";
            imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
            dataBase db=new dataBase(context);
            db.setimageStatus(Integer.valueOf(result),1);
            items.get(position).setimageStatus(1);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem related to your list height.

Verify that the list height is defined as fill_parent and not wrap_content.

Also, you should check out [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It is an open source lib for asynchronous loading, caching and displaying images on Android.

Comment: Thanks, i tried fill_parent, but problem is continuing. Can image loader save local storage?

Comment: From the Universal Image Loader documentation: Possibility of image caching in memory and/or on device's file sysytem (or SD card)